How to determine what length and diameter GRK RSS screw to use?
I am planning out building an 8'x14' pergola. I am going to use pressure treated 6x6's for the posts and pressure treated 2x8's for the beams (14ft long). I've just learned about GRK RSS screws and would like to use those but am having trouble understanding how to calculate or determine what diameter and length screw I'm supposed to use.
So far, I've gathered that the screw length should be the length of the top attachment plus ⅔ of the bottom layer depth (so in my case, 1.5" from the 2x8 and 3 ⅔" is 2/3 of a 6x6 so I would use a 5 1/8" length screw?). Is this thought process correct?
As for how to pick the diameter of the screw - I'm very lost there. Any guidance would be so helpful.
Thank you

What you do is figure out the required strength and use the appropriate fasteners.
Once you're into the back piece by twice the thickness of the front piece that's probably enough.
With self-drilling structural screw the main thing to do is make sure the screw you use has a non threaded section long enough to reach through the front piece else you resk jacking the two pieces apart instead of clamping them together.
2/3 embedment, is a fine goal, but in reality you are  constrained by the design of the screws, it's only the threaded part that does the clamping. you need to get all of that into the back piece.  the screws intended fastenining "2 inch" lumber will probably be the 5-1/8 you mention above.

this a very helpful. lots of new puzzle pieces for my knowledge bank here. thank you so much.
Do you mind to explain what you mean by "What you do is figure out the required strength"? Does this apply to how to determine diameter of what screw I need?

to determione the diameter you need to know hos strong it needs to be then you look up the strength with the manufacturer....
